# Creating Readonly Variables in Stimulsoft

Tags: c#, stimulsoft

I'm a Noobie to Stimulsoft. I have Stimulsoft Version 2015.3 running for our apps in Visual Studio 2013.

[image: stimulsoft]

Example videos found on YouTube are all old, and I have not found any to show how to create a variable using their built-in conditional logic.

There is a dictionary where variables are created:

[image: dictionary]

Currently, if I try to compile, I have 10 errors as shown here:

[image: 10 Errors]

I'll focus on the first one: `decInvoiceCost`.

The error says ";" expected, and gives this little preview:

[image: ; expected]

The code for it, entered using their editor, is:

```
{if (blnUseMarketCost) { VwInvoice.MarketCost } else { VwInvoice.AverageCost } }
```

where `blnUseMarketCost` is a Boolean, and the two (2) decimal values `MarketCost` and `AverageCost` come from the database view.

Back in the error, if I click "Go to Code":

[image: Go to Code]

...I am taken to the source code which is rendered by their designer:

```
    public virtual decimal decInvoiceCost
    {
        get
        {
            // CheckerInfo: Value decInvoiceCost
            return {if (blnUseMarketCost) { VwInvoiceDetail.MarketCostInInvPricingUnit } else { VwInvoiceDetail.AverageCostInInvPricingUnit } }m;
        }
    }
```

I think that **"m"** on the end is causing some issues, but I don't really know.

### Does anyone have a few current examples showing how to use basic logic in these variable fields?

**UPDATE**

The C# code of the report is generated by the designer. I can use it to see what the designer is trying to do, but I do not understand all of the nuances.

```
namespace Reports
{
    public class Report : Stimulsoft.Report.StiReport
    {
        public Report()        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        #region StiReport Designer generated code - do not modify
        // 
        // {snip}
        // 
        public virtual decimal decMarkup
        {
            get
            {
                // CheckerInfo: Value decMarkup
                return ((decInvoiceCost==0) ? 0 : (decInvoiceProfit / decInvoiceCost))m;
            }
        }
        // 
        // {snip}
        // 
        #endregion StiReport Designer generated code - do not modify
    }
}
```

[image: Screenshot of Stimulsoft IDE]

Comment: You have flagged this question as C# and Stimulsoft. As I have never use Stimulsoft I'll have to know whether this uses regular C# before throwing some C# knowledge at it. Is that the case?

Comment: C# is what the report tool uses to generate the designer code. It has a line up top that says do not modify, because it is auto generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Eureka!

I found the answer!

In the Stimulsoft variable editor, there is an option called **Init by:** that is prefilled to **Value**.

I changed **Init by:** to **Expression**, and the report does now pull data:

[image: screenshot of Init by]

The Code View does not appear to be any different:

```
 public virtual decimal decMarkup
 {
     get
     {
         // CheckerInfo: Value decMarkup
         return ((decInvoiceCost==0) ? 0 : (decInvoiceProfit / decInvoiceCost))m;
     }
 }
```

The [Stimulsoft Reports Documentation on Conditional Expressions](http://admin.stimulsoft.com/Documentation/Online/index.html?report_internals_expressions_functions_in_expressions.htm) makes no mention of this.

There are not many questions on here about Stimulsoft, and even fewer of them have answers. So, I hope someone else gets use out of this.

Answer (score 2):

The code for the `decInvoiceCost` get implementation is invalid. You should use either of these implementations instead:

```
public virtual decimal decInvoiceCost
{
    get
    {
        // CheckerInfo: Value decInvoiceCost
        if (blnUseMarketCost) 
            return VwInvoiceDetail.MarketCostInInvPricingUnit;
        else 
            return VwInvoiceDetail.AverageCostInInvPricingUnit;
    }
}
```

this will return either one of the two values based on an if statement.

or

```
public virtual decimal decInvoiceCost
{
    get
    {
        // CheckerInfo: Value decInvoiceCost
        return blnUseMarketCost
           ? VwInvoiceDetail.MarketCostInInvPricingUnit
           : VwInvoiceDetail.AverageCostInInvPricingUnit;
    }
}
```

which uses the ternary operator `<boolExpr> ? <valueifTrue> : <valueIfFalse>;`

Comment: This would be the solution I would have proposed as well. Generally I would prefer the first version. The second one is fine as well but the ternary operator tends to become unreadable when adding more code.

Comment: The first way will not work because the code is generated automatically.

Answer (score 1):

You should use an expression there that returns a value. The if statement is not an expression. Try to use the conditional operator (?:).

Comment: Here is one using the conditional operator: [Screenshot of Stimulsoft Error](http://i.imgur.com/2PxFt5Q.png). Can you show me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I have updated my question to include that image, but the linked version I posted above is full size. StackOverflow shrunk the one I posted in the main question.

Comment: Yes. I didn't see this on your first screenshot. The **Init by** should be set to **Expression**.

Answer (score 1):

The updated version helps a lot. It seems Stimulsoft expects a constant number in form of a literal there (e.g. 5.0 or 7.4 ...). It then tries to mark it as a decimal for the compiler (more info here [Letter after a number, what is it called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6681112/letter-after-a-number-what-is-it-called)).

This means that it does NOT expect a calculation, decision or code. I have never used the software so I can only guess how to solve that issue. This is why I struggled whether I should submit this as an answer. My first guess would be to change the `Init by:` or the second `Type` Dropdown to something else than `value`. Something like `code`, `calculation` or similar would be what I am looking for.

The other properties seem to handle code/calculation just fine so try to look what those are using.

Comment: You posted this as I was also posting my answer. You caught the **Init by:** bit, too. The **Type:** options are `{Value, Nullable Value, List, Range}`.